# Colormap in 2d plots in Scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

When using the `plot(y)` function in Scilab, being `y` a real matrix, multiple data curves are plotted on a 2d plot and the color of each curve is automatically set.

According to Scilab online help, a default color table is used (the command cycles the table and colors each curve accordingly):
http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/plot.html

The problem is that the default table lists only 7 colors, so the 8th data curve will have the same color as the 1st, and so on.

Is there a way to extend this table, to automatically color more than 7 data curves with distinct colors?

I tried using the `colormap` as in 3d plots, but didn't worked.

```
f = scf();
plot(myData);
f.color_map = jetcolormap(32);
```

I think this only works for 3d plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to set the foreground color using [gce()](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/gce.html).

### Example

```
clf()

number_of_points=100;
number_of_lines=42;

x=[1:number_of_points]

for line_number = 1:number_of_lines
    plot(x, x+line_number);
    last_line = gce();
    last_line.children.foreground = line_number;
end

f = gcf();
f.color_map= jetcolormap(number_of_lines);
```

### Result

[image: Plot]